# MongoDB findOne returns null after server restart

Tags: node.js, mongodb

first time posting a question here.
I have multiple post requests coming into a nodejs server per second with different IDs as strings to determine who they are from.
It works as intended most of the time but when restarting the server to push updates it fails consistently.

```
 db.findOne({ID: req.body.ID})

            .then(function(data){
                if(data) // goes on and does things with the data
                else { 
                      db.insertOne(req.body, () => {
                            resolve(console.log("New user created"))
                      })
                }
              }) //a few other then blocks and a catch block that I don't think are relevant
```

I'm pretty new to all this stuff, but it seems to work exactly as I intend for most of the time besides server restarts. It will create multiple new entries per restart for the same user sometimes 3 or more before it starts to return valid values on the findOne request

I've tried putting in more findOne checks for other values but they are all returning null after a server restart.

It's a Heroku server running nodejs with express and mongodb as the only packages
the server opens a connection to Mongodb first thing

```
dotenv.config()
const mongodb = require('mongodb')

mongodb.connect(process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, function(err, client){
    module.exports = client.db().collection('userdata')
    const app = require("./app")
    app.listen(process.env.PORT)
})
```

and I included the collection name in "db" since I only ever use one collection.

edit:
I can't recreate the problem with only one user sending post requests, it only happens when multiple users are sending post requests and the node js server is being restarted

Comment: Did the mongodb server also restart with your app? If yes then check if your mongodb server persist data on restart or not

Comment: I don't think mongodb is restarting when I restart my app, but mongodb is persistent.